# The message could not be posted to this Wall

Tags: facebook, share

I have a facebook page in which I have implemented a tab. Whenever people that aren't me try to share something from the tab, they get the following message: "The message could not be posted to this Wall."

From googling around, I couldn't find any hint why this was happening...

**EDIT:**

The url I was trying to share had "www.facebook.com" in it. If I change "facebook" to anything else, it allows me to share...

Comment: Are you trying to share content which is not publicly accessible?

Comment: [Sandbox mode](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#sandbox) - this is the most common cause of things not working for anyone other than the developer/admin. Make sure your application is **not** in sandbox mode.

Comment: Lix - the app isn't in sandbox mode... for some reason, my personal account (the page's creator) can share, other people get that annoying message - even after I have added them as page admins.

Comment: Igy - how can I check if the content is publicly accessible? like I wrote to Lix - I am able to share, others cannot.